# help with home work 2nd grade

Tags: single-word-requests

what's the word 3 letters answer to: 
came to know or understand, recognized

Comment: You can try *saw*. But this really isn't the place to ask homework questions, Augusto.

Comment: "Met" is another word that might be (archaically) used in this sense.

Comment: Could also be ***got***.  After thinking about it for a awhile he finally *got* it.  Or  the teacher explained it again and now I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Ken. But that isn’t a common second grade word. Are you a parent working from an online source?  If it’s from a teacher there should be a master list to practice from.